# MySQL won't start in Debian

Tags: mysql-5.5

I'm very new to the Linux world. I have been trying to connect to MySQL but kept getting various errors.  Below are the three commands I started in that order.
Running the second command was a result of me researching about the error generated in the first command and etc.

Can someone take a look at the below and provide me with some help/suggestion?
Also I can't find the "mysqld.sock" anywhere on the system.

Thank you

> ------------------ root@MYSQL011:/tmp# mysql -u root -p Enter password: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server
>   through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) root@MYSQL011:/tmp#
>
> ------------------ root@MYSQL011:/tmp# service mysql status
>
> ? mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
>   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)    Active: failed (Result:
>   exit-code) since Tue 2017-04-18 11:00:41 EDT; 23min ago   Process:
>   5360 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Apr 18 11:00:41 MYSQL011 mysql[5360]: Starting MySQL database server:
>   mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
>   failed! Apr 18 11:00:41 MYSQL011 systemd[1]: mysql.service: control
>   process exited, code=exited status=1 Apr 18 11:00:41 MYSQL011
>   systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database
>   server daemon. Apr 18 11:00:41 MYSQL011 systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service
>   entered failed state.
>
> ------------------ root@MYSQL011:/tmp# journalctl -xn
>
> -- Logs begin at Wed 2017-04-12 11:02:35 EDT, end at Tue 2017-04-18 11:20:22 EDT. -- Apr 18 11:00:41 MYSQL011 mysql[5360]: Starting MySQL
>   database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
>   . . . . . . . failed! Apr 18 11:00:41 MYSQL011 systemd[1]:
>   mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1 Apr 18
>   11:00:41 MYSQL011 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the
>   mysql database server daemon.
>   -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> ### -- Unit mysql.service has failed.
>
> -- The result is failed. Apr 18 11:00:41 MYSQL011 systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state. Apr 18 11:06:23 MYSQL011
>   sshd[5175]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user xyz Apr 18
>   11:17:01 MYSQL011 CRON[6116]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened
>   for user root by (uid=0) Apr 18 11:17:01 MYSQL011 CRON[6117]: (root)
>   CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly) Apr 18 11:17:01
>   MYSQL011 CRON[6116]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user
>   root Apr 18 11:20:22 MYSQL011 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of
>   Temporary Directories...
>   -- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun with start-up
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> -- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up. Apr 18 11:20:22 MYSQL011 systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary
>   Directories.
>   -- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> ### -- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.
>
> -- The start-up result is done. root@MYSQL011:/tmp#

Comment: Try this:

    Sudo mysql -u root -p Enter password:

Otherwise, I'd follow this guide to getting mysql running. I got it running on a flavor of debian, maybe there's something in this [tutorial](https://www.stewright.me/2014/06/tutorial-install-mysql-server-on-raspberry-pi/) you missed?

Comment: I just checked out the link provided in that tutorial.  But that's for installing mysql on rasperry pi.  Would that apply in my environment?  Thanks

Comment: Maybe. I run Raspbian on it. "Raspbian is a free operating system based on Debian optimized for the Raspberry Pi hardware. An operating system is the set of basic programs and utilities that make your Raspberry Pi run. However, Raspbian provides more than a pure OS: it comes with over 35,000 packages, pre-compiled software bundled in a nice format for easy installation on your Raspberry Pi." I would at least use the tutorial to see what is different compared to your installation and that may help provide clues as a quick spot check.

Comment: Does anyone know how to re-create the "mysqld.sock" file?

Comment: It is re-created when you start and stop the service. https://serverfault.com/questions/279366/what-should-mysqld-sock-contain-why-dont-i-have-it

Comment: i tried that before posting.  i ran "service mysql stop/start".  The stop worked but the start failed.

Comment: Here's the error on "start" root@MYSQL011:/# service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57303/discussion-between-shaulinator-and-sydney).